# Column of generic/variable type?

Tags: database-design, datatypes, blob

In SQL, I would like to create a table which can contain generic data types. This types can change from every row. The solution I could come up to is:

```
CREATE TABLE TagValue
(
     tag VARCHAR(64),
     value BLOB,
     type INTEGER,
     PRIMARY KEY(tag)
);
```

Here in the 'type' column I put the type of data contained in value.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: ***What*** concrete database system? More advanced things like blob store are *not* part of "core" SQL query language - but they are highly vendor-specific - so we need to know what database this is for

Comment: @marc_s: The DB I am going to use will probably be PostgreSQL, but my question does not intend to be database specific.

Answer (score 1):

Why BLOB ? 
Why not string or varbinary(max) or nvarchar
Dot Net Nuke in their database inside table UserProfile have generc column

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserProfile](
    [ProfileID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PropertyDefinitionID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PropertyValue] [nvarchar](3750) NULL,
    [PropertyText] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Visibility] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LastUpdatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ExtendedVisibility] [varchar](400) NULL ....
```

Comment: I put a BLOB in case I have to store, e.g., an integer or an image. Does it have issues with space in case of small data values?